# Mongo db php driver class

Tags: php, mongodb

My phpinfo() has the following under the mongodb section

mongodb
mongodb support enabled
mongodb version     1.1.7
mongodb stability   stable
libmongoc version   1.3.5
libbson version     1.3.5

Mongod is running, but when I try to instantiate the Mongo class I get

Fatal error: Class 'Mongo' not found in ...

Am I missing a step here? I've set up this same environment before and never had this problem.

Also,
Fatal error: Class 'MongoClient' not found in ... as well

Comment: I don't have an answer, but others are more likely to help you if you post the problematic lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing the Mongo drivers:

[Legacy driver](http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.installation.php) (deprecated): mongo.so

- Provides the classes you try to intantiate.

[Recent driver](http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.installation.pecl.php): mongodb.so

- "provides a minimal API for core driver functionality"

With your installed driver, you cannot use the Classes provided by the legacy driver.